# Use google apps script to close a dialogue box launched via SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Alert Dialog');

Tags: google-apps-script

Using GAS, I would like to launch a message box, run code, and then close the message box on the other side with code. I understand that this cannot be done with ui.alerts but believe it can be done via html. Here's my attempt. The box opens, of course, but I can't find any way to close it.

```
function testing() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<div><h2>Message</h2><p>This is an alert message.</p></div>');
  var dialog = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Alert Dialog');

  Logger.log('Intervening code etc.')

  dialog.close();

};
```

That last command (dialog.close()) does not work.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Closing a Dialog**

Using google.script.host.close() and a short delay through onSuccessHandler

It's in the javascript of your html

```
function testing() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<div><h2>Message</h2><p>This is an alert message.</p></div><script>window.onload = () => { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {google.script.host.close()}).dela()}</script>');
  var dialog = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Alert Dialog');
  Logger.log('Intervening code etc.');
}

function dela() {
  //Utilities.sleep(2000);//optional for longer delays
  return;
}
```

Note: google.script.host.close() does not work on web apps